# Как решить проблему с access denied в s3 amazon?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon, amazon-s3

Как настроить доступ к просмотру изображений для всех пользователей?

если пробовать стучаться к `https://florachaing-ru.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/shops/2/clients/1de7e82ec6c4ef96472f4d2f7c8e41ba.jpeg`

выдает

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>21E0167572B6E56E</RequestId>
<HostId>2kdjr7LFuMjhBRJd43EmPreEW3mROi4opteaFRg1q6wiyh2yMs/PQxDWXyVIYd14Q2ANJoI7GEk=</HostId>
</Error>
```

проект на ларавел и загрузка, удаление просиходит без проблем, но в браузере не показывает

Answer (score 1):

Buckets > BUCKET_NAME > Permissions > Bucket policy > Edit

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```